# Riffle multiple lists together

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to write a function which will take multiple lists of function parameters and riffle all of their parameters together as input for a function. To be more explicit, consider if I had the following lists of parameters:
`P1={a1,a2,a3,...,an}, P2={b1,b2,b3,...,bn}...`. I then want to write a function, say called `riffleParams`, that will do the following:

`riffleParams[P1,P2,P3,...PN]={{a1,b1,c1,...},{a2,b1,c1,...},...}`

Or in more concrete terms, you would have

`riffleParams[{a,b},{1,2,3,4}]={{a,1},{b,1},{a,2},{b,2},{a,3},{b,3},{a,4},{b,4}}`

I can think of some nasty ways to do this but extending it to arbitrary number of input parameter lists seems tricky. I figure there is probably a cleaner way to implement it that I'm not familiar with. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: `Tuples[]` does a different arrangement: `Tuples[{{a, b}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]`; nevertheless, maybe it is useful for you?

Comment: Ah, that works fine! I knew there would be some built-in to do this... Not sure how to accept an answer from the comments, but thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Tuples[]` does it:

```
Tuples[{{a, b}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
   {{a, 1}, {a, 2}, {a, 3}, {a, 4}, {b, 1}, {b, 2}, {b, 3}, {b, 4}}
```

Before `Tuples[]` became a built-in function, one used to use `Outer[]` for the task, in conjunction with `Flatten[]`:

```
Flatten[Outer[List, {a, b}, {1, 2, 3, 4}], 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

There is also: [`Distribute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html)

```
Distribute[{{a, b}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, List]
```

> {{a, 1}, {a, 2}, {a, 3}, {a, 4}, {b, 1}, {b, 2}, {b, 3}, {b, 4}}